# Why do I get this error when installing TensorFlow.JS?

Tags: node.js, npm, tensorflow.js

I'm using `Node.js v18.17.1` and I'm trying to install TensorFlow.JS using the `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node` command and I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\\Desktop\OutfitOracle\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-windows-4.11.0.zip
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.9.1.zip
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR!
npm ERR! * Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
npm ERR! symlink ./lib/napi-v9 failed:  Error: Command failed: node scripts/deps-stage.js symlink ./lib/napi-v9
npm ERR!   * Symlink of lib\napi-v9\tensorflow.dll failed, creating a copy on disk.
npm ERR! node:internal/process/promises:288
npm ERR!             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
npm ERR!             ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\\Desktop\OutfitOracle\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\deps\lib\tensorflow.dll' -> 'C:\Users\\Desktop\OutfitOracle\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v9\tensorflow.dll'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4058,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'copyfile',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\OutfitOracle\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\deps\\lib\\tensorflow.dll',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\OutfitOracle\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v9\\tensorflow.dll'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.17.1
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
npm ERR!   code: 1,
npm ERR!   killed: false,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   cmd: 'node scripts/deps-stage.js symlink ./lib/napi-v9'
npm ERR! }
```